# Проблемы с сохранением настроек

Tags: java, android

Сохраняю настройки по одной вот так:

```
public void SaveMySet(String name_znach, int znach) {
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putInt(name_znach, znach);
    ed.apply(); //сохранили в настройках
    ed.commit();
}
```

Загружаю сразу все настройки:

```
public void LoadMySet() {
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String str_SID = "";
    nach_0 = (byte) sPref.getInt("nach_0", 7);
    HZn = (byte) sPref.getInt("HZn", 1);
    HPl = (byte) sPref.getInt("HPl", 1);
    nKntScr = (byte) sPref.getInt("KntScr", 1);
    String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sp_KntScr);
    KntScr = Double.parseDouble(choose[nKntScr]);
}
```

НО! Сохраняясь в одной Активити, эти настройки в другой Активити уже не прочитать, приходится тащить вот так:

```
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, SetScrAct.class);
    intent.putExtra("nach_0", nach_0);
    intent.putExtra("HZn", HZn);
```

Вопрос: можно ли, из любой Активити сохранять все настройки в одном месте?

Comment: Это должно работать. Попробуйте не вызывать лишний коммит, все строки в константы вывести и использовать глобальные преференсы `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context);`

Comment: `apply()` и `commit()` делает [одно и то же](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php#save) (только первый - асинхронно) - один из этих методов лишний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте таблицу в SQLite, продумайте типы значений и количество столбцов и при каждом изменении в одном Activity сохраняйте настройки в БД. В другом Activity при загрузке извлеките значения из таблицы. В случае изменения значений и во втором Activity опять сохраните в БД. Немного потрудившись с таблицой, внесением и извлечением ваш вопрос разрешится.